# InvokeClrInstanceMethod - "Length cannot be less than zero"

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I try to import data from .csv file, but get an error.

When i try to copy data from .csv to staging table it crashes with the following message:

NAME:

```
ex
```

VALUE:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Length cannot be less than zero.
```

Parameter name:

length

at

Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Tools.DMF.ServiceProxy.DmfEntityProxy.DoWork[T](Func`1 work)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at

Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.ManagedInterop.ClrBridgeImpl.InvokeClrInstanceMethod(ClrBridgeImpl* , ObjectWrapper* objectWrapper, Char* pszMethodName, Int32 argsLength, ObjectWrapper** arguments, Boolean* argsAreByRef, Boolean* isException)

As far as it is a .dll (Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Framework.Tools.DMF.ServiceProxy.DmfEntityProxy) i cannot go inside it to view where the problem actually appears with debugger.

Comment: Can you share your code to give you an accurate answer?

Answer (score 0):

When related to DMF, errors aren't very descriptive.

Can't help you much, since don't have the file neither know your processing group confguration. Here are a few thing you may like to consider:

- Make sure that you have the correct amount of columns in your file, there may be missing one
- Verify the list of mandatory columns, make sure that this columns are in the correct position inside the file
- Double check the configuration, make sure that all columns have the corresponding data type and length

Cheers!